# Wordpress %20 issue with url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue with WordPress using for eCommerce purpose I am using flatsome theme with woo-commerce. The problem is when I go click on any link related to my-account it give a page which says `access forbidden` and add `%20` at the end of the link.

Is there any way to remove `%20` from end of this url? 
[here is the image related to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS3Lf.png)

Comment: add this to .htaccess `RewriteRule (.*)\ (.*) $1-$2`

Comment: where can i add this in wordpress .htaccess?

Comment: check my answer /

Comment: i tried this but issue is still there @GovindKumar

Comment: You probably have a trailing space (spaces are encoded as `%20` in URLs) in your links. Check you HTML (or PHP) `<a href="">` values.

Comment: where i can check that in wordpress? @JordiNebot

Comment: If you don't have direct access to your server's code, you could check it in `Appearance > Editor`.

Comment: Check you permalink settings seems like you have space there.
Can you access non-woo-commerce pages ?

Comment: yes i have checked that out too but resolved it by making some changes into the theme.